# Subroutine inside OpenMP PARALLEL DO - Program Crash

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, subroutine

I have read both [Calling an internal subroutine inside OpenMP region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628034/calling-an-internal-subroutine-inside-openmp-region) and [Global Variables in Fortran OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832457/global-variables-in-fortran-openmp). My understanding ([from here](http://www.training.prace-ri.eu/uploads/tx_pracetmo/FurtherTopics.pdf)) is that:

- Variables in the argument list inherit their data scope attribute from the calling routine.
- COMMON blocks or module variables in Fortran are shared, unless declared THREADPRIVATE.
- SAVE variables in Fortran are shared.
- All other local variables are private.

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(j,dummy1,dummy2,dummy3,dummy4)
DO j=1,ntotal
  dummy1 = 0.0d0
  dummy2 = foo(j)
  CALL kernel(dummy1,dummy1,dummy2,dummy3,dummy4)  
  Variable(j) = dummy3 + dummy4
END DO 
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

The subroutine kernel then takes IN dummy1, and dummy2 and puts OUT dummy3 and dummy4. I compile with:

```
 -fopenmp -fno-automatic -fcheck=all
```

I get:

```
Fortran runtime error: Recursive call to nonrecursive procedure 'kernel'
```

Which from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html) I understand is expected. When I compile without the -fcheck sometimes the code passes the subroutine call without incident but the majority of the time it will crash with no error. I am guessing this is because my subroutine is not thread safe. All the arguments passed to the subroutine should be private and individual for each thread. The trimmed down subroutine is as follows:

```
SUBROUTINE kernel(r,dx,hsml,w,dwdx)   

  USE Initial_Parameters
  IMPLICIT NONE 

  ! DATA DICTIONARY: DECLARE CALLING PARAMETER TYPES AND DEFINITIONS
  REAL(KIND=dp), INTENT(IN)                 ::  r           
  REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(dim), INTENT(IN) ::  dx          
  REAL(KIND=dp), INTENT(IN)                 ::  hsml        
  REAL(KIND=dp), INTENT(OUT)                ::  w           
  REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(dim), INTENT(OUT)::  dwdx        
  ! DATA DICTIONARY: DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLE TYPES AND DEFINITIONS
  INTEGER                                   ::  i, d  
  REAL(KIND=dp)                             ::  q, dw
  REAL(KIND=dp)                             ::  factor      


  ! Kernel functions are funcitons of q, the distance between particles
  ! divided by the smoothing length  
  q = r/hsml 
  ! Preset the kernel to zero
  w = 0.e0
  ! Preset the derivative of the kernel to zero
  DO d=1,dim         
    dwdx(d) = 0.e0
  END DO   

  IF (skf == 1) THEN     

    ! If the problem is one dimensional then,
    IF (dim == 1) THEN
      ! The coefficient, alpha = factor is given by:
      factor = 1.e0/hsml
    ! If the problem is two dimensional then,
    ELSE IF (dim == 2) THEN
      ! The coefficient, alpha = factor is given by:
      factor = 15.e0/(7.e0*pi*hsml*hsml)
    ! If the problem is two dimensional then,
    ELSE IF (dim == 3) THEN
      ! The coefficient, alpha = factor is given by:
      factor = 3.e0/(2.e0*pi*hsml*hsml*hsml)
    ! If the dimension value is not 1, 2 or 3 then there is a problem.
    ELSE
       WRITE(*,*)' >>> Error <<< : Wrong dimension: Dim =',dim
       STOP
    END IF

    ! Smoothing function for 1st range of q.                                         
    IF (q >= 0 .AND. q <= 1.e0) THEN
      ! The smoothing function is given by:
      w = factor * (2./3. - q*q + q*q*q / 2.)
      ! For each dimension work out the gradient of the smoothing function
      DO d = 1, dim
        dwdx(d) = factor * (-2.+3./2.*q)/hsml**2 * dx(d)       
      END DO   

    ! Smoothing function for 2nd range of q.  
    ELSE IF (q > 1.e0 .AND. q <= 2) THEN  
      ! Smoothing function is equal to:        
      w = factor * 1.e0/6.e0 * (2.-q)**3 
      ! Gadient of the smoothing function in each dimension.
      DO d = 1, dim
        dwdx(d) =-factor * 1.e0/6.e0 * 3.*(2.-q)**2/hsml * (dx(d)/r)        
      END DO   

    ! Smoothing function and gradient for all other values of q is zero.
    ELSE
      ! Smoothing function is equal to: 
      w=0.
      ! Gadient of the smoothing function in each dimension.
      DO d= 1, dim
        dwdx(d) = 0.
      END DO             
    END IF     

END SUBROUTINE kernel
```

The local variables should be private and all the argumets which have been passed are private. The module parameters are shared but this is fine. Could you please explain why this crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-fno-automatic` the local variables in `kernel` will be implicitly `SAVE`d. The description [here](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/finterp10.html#interp3) notes

> Local variables with the SAVE attribute declared in procedures called from a parallel region are implicitly SHARED.

As such, `kernel` is indeed not thread-safe (as I understand it).

Note also in your example you pass `dummy1` as the first and second arguments to `kernel`, but your definition of this routine specifies the first argument (`r`) in a scalar whilst the second (`dx`) is an array of length `dim`. I'm not sure if this is just a product of your minimal example or of your real code, but this could cause issues. Are you declaring `kernel` inside a module and then using the module? This will generate interfaces which should help catch this sort of thing.

Comment: It's a product of the minimal example. For this example, the code is 1D (dim=1) so it hopefully shouldn't make a difference. Kernel is not in a module it is a stand-alone subroutine.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion  If I try to compile something that looks like this I get `Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'b' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)` but if I put the `subroutine` inside a `contains` section (i.e. an interface exists) this becomes `Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'b' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)` so I'd be careful with this approach.

Comment: Without `-fno-automatic` the code will compile but not run at all. @d_1999 I'll investigate this further.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion One (not very nice) workaround would be to pass in the local work variables (`i`, `d`, ...) from the calling loop, allowing you to declare them as private in the openmp pragma.

Comment: All subroutines now in a module. Fixed the rank mismatch but passing a rank-1 array. Without -fno-automatic the executable crashes immediately, even if I set it to only have 1 thread. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: @1QuickQuestion Does it still crash if you compile without `-fopenmp`? What is the nature of the crash? If you can update your question with a (new) minimal+complete example then it will be much easier for others to try to reproduce the error and identify the source of the issues. One option is to remove `-fno-automatic` and add `-fmax-stack-var-size=X` where `X` is some small variable. I wonder if you're just running out of stack space. Can you try running `ulimit -s` and report the stack size? Try running `ulimit -s unlimited` and then running the code compiled without `-fno-automatic`.

Comment: The code works fine in serial without `-fopenmp`. `ulimit -s` produces 2047. `ulimit -s unlimited` returns "bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument" (running MinGW on Windows). Compiling with `-fmax-stack-var-size=2047` seems to work, thank you.