# Calling subroutine in parallel environment

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

I think my problem is related or even identical to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628034/). But I don't understand what's actually happening.

I'm using openMP with the gfortran compiler and I have the following task to do: I have a density distribution `F(X, Y)` on a two-dimensional surface with x-coordinates `X` and y-coordinates `Y`. The matrix `F` has the size `Nx` x `Ny`.

I now have a set of coordinates `Xp(i)` and `Yp(i)` and I need to interpolate the density `F` onto these points. This problem is made for parallelization.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(i)
    do i=1, Nmax

        ! Some stuff to be done here

        Fint(i) = interp2d(Xp(i), Yp(i), X, Y, F, Nx, Ny)

        ! Some other stuff to be done here

    end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Everything is shared except for `i`. The function `interp2d` is doing some simple linear interpolation.

That works fine with one thread but fails with multithreading. I traced the problem down to the `hunt`-subroutine taken from Numerical Recipes, which gets called by `interp2d`. The `hunt`-subroutine basically calculates the index `ix` such that `X(ix) <= Xp(i) < X(ix+1)`. This is needed to get the starting point for the interpolation.

With multithreading it happens every now and then, that one threads gets the correct index `ix` from `hunt` and the thread, that calls `hunt` next gets the exact same index, even though `Xp(i)` is not even close to that point.

I can prevent this by using the `CRITICAL` environment:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(i)
    do i=1, Nmax

        ! Some stuff to be done here

  !$OMP CRITICAL
        Fint(i) = interp2d(Xp(i), Yp(i), X, Y, F, Nx, Ny)
  !$OMP END CRITICAL

        ! Some other stuff to be done here

    end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

But this decreases the efficiency. If I use for example three threads, I have a load average of 1.5 with the `CRITICAL` environment. Without I have a load average of 2.75, but wrong results and even sometimes a `SIGSEGV` runtime error.

What exactly is happening here? It seems to me that all the threads are calling the same `hunt`-subroutine and if they do it at the same time there is a conflict. Does that make sense?

How can I prevent this?

Comment: It looks like the `hunt` subroutine isn't thread-safe. Just move your `critical` directive away from the call to `interp2d` down to the call to `hunt` inside `interp2d` (or as low as you can).

Comment: Could you post the code of the `interp2d` and `hunt` routines?

Usually, When you need a `critical` to make a code work, it's because  you have a shared resource (e.g. a variable) that is read and written by several threads at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post the subroutine from Numerical Recipes here. But I will post something simplified later.
By now, I think that all threads are accessing the same stack and sometimes, depending on the execution time of the routines, they are not reading the dummy variables in the right order from the stack. Does that make any sense?
Can I force every thread to have it's own private stack?

Comment: I think I found the problem:
Declaring all dummy variables as `THREADPRIVATE` seems to help. I will check.

Comment: `hunt` from the Fortran 77 version of Numerical Recipes seems thread-safe. My best guess is that you have unintentionally made some local variable(s) in `interp2d` static by combining the declaration and the initialisation, e.g., `integer :: i = 0`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Damn! That's it! I wasn't aware that it makes a difference when you combine declaration and initialization... Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for better visibility. Fortran 90 is just one specific (and old) version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining variable declaration and initialisation in Fortran 90+ has the side effect of giving the variable the `SAVE` attribute.

```
integer :: i = 0
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
integer, save :: i

if (first_invocation) then
  i = 0
end if
```

`SAVE`'d variables retain their value between multiple invocations of the routine and are therefore often implemented as static variables. By the rules governing the implicit data sharing classes in OpenMP, such variables are shared unless listed in a `threadprivate` directive.

OpenMP mandates that compliant compilers should apply the above semantics even when the underlying language is Fortran 77.